# Classification of 2D time dependent diffusion equation

Tags: diffusion

I was trying to classify the following PDE:

$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}=\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x^2}}+\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{y^2}}$$

where $u = u(x,y,t)$. I was originally using the definition of $B^2-4AC$ and found this equation to be elliptic, which is true for the Laplace equation however I was wondering if the dependence on time changes this. I was also wondering if this PDE is inhomogeneous and linear? Thank you!

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this maths question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

homogenous, linear and parabolic.

In a generalization of the 2-dimensional equation, any equation of the form
$$
\partial_t y = -L u
$$
where $L$ is positive elliptic (such as $-\nabla^2$) is said to be parabolic. It shares with the 2d case the fact that it has well defined solutions with inital value data an a line with $t=constant$.

Comment: thank you! could you please explain why it is parabolic?

Comment: Added a note to my rather short (because of lack of time) original answer.